# Homotopy type of manifolds homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary

Tags: manifolds, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, compact-manifolds

Let $M$ be a topological manifold which is homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary.
This extends the class of compact manifolds and is sometimes called being *of finite topological type*.

What can be said about the CW-complex of $M$?

For example, I'm concerned about the following question:

> Does $M$ have the homotopy type of a CW-complex of *finite type*, i.e. a CW-complex whose skeletons are finite?

If I remember correctly, topological manifolds have the homotopy type of CW-complexes and compact manifolds have the homotopy type of finite CW-complexes. So this would fit the picture.

Comment: Notice that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to the compact manifold with boundary of which $M$ is the interior...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was discussed several times at MSE (at least [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648250/spaces-homotopy-equivalent-to-finite-cw-complexes?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented/745823#745823)). The simplest (still quite hard) proof that each compact manifold is homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex is due to Chapman, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented/745823#745823). By Brown's theorem, every topological manifold $M$ with boundary is collarable (the boundary admits a product neighborhood, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703009/collar-neighbourhoods-for-topological-manifolds)) it follows that $int(M)$ is homotopy-equivalent to $M$. See also Grumpy's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/homotopy-type-of-the-manifold-minus-the-boundary?rq=1) in the smooth case.