# Is being "homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary" preserved under finite coverings?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, covering-spaces

Let $M$ be a topological manifold such that $M$ is homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary. Let $f \colon M' \to M$ be a finitely-sheeted covering.

Is then also $M'$ homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary?

Comment: What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: Sorry, you are right that I should have included some motivation. It's just that this is used in some papers (geometric topology) without further explanation, so I definitely think it's true - but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: OK, then try to prove first that a finite covering of a compact manifold with boundary is again a compact manifold with boundary.  Then read my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909517/homotopy-type-of-manifolds-homeomorphic-to-the-interior-of-a-compact-manifold-wi?rq=1

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you for the hint. I understand that a covering space of a compact space by a finite covering is compact again. So we have $M \cong N^\circ$ where $N$ is a compact manifold with boundary and using the covering $f$, we get a covering $M' \to N^\circ$. But I don't see how I can 'add a boundary' to the covering space $M'$ which matches $\partial N$ under the covering. If I could, I would be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the terminology: A topological manifold $M$ is called **tame** if it is homeomorphic to the interior of a compact topological manifold with boundary. Here is one nontrivial fact that you need to know: If $N$ is a topological manifold with boundary then the inclusion map $int(N)\to N$ is a homotopy-equivalence. This is a corollary of the existence of a collar around the boundary of $N$, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703009/collar-neighbourhoods-for-topological-manifolds). 
In particular,  given $x\in int(N)$, the induced map $\pi_1(int(N),x)\to \pi_1(N,x)$ is an isomorphism. (One can in principle prove it with bare hands, without using Brown's theorem, but why bother...)

Once you know this, the rest is just the basic covering theory which you can find either in Hatcher or in Massey.

Suppose that $M$ is a connected tame manifold (I will leave it to you to deal with the case of non-connected manifolds), $N$ is a compact manifold with boundary, $f: M\to int(N)$ is a homeomorphism. Let $p: M'\to M$ be a covering map (finite or not is irrelevant at this point). Then $p$ is determined by a certain subgroup $H\le \pi_1(M,y)$. Using the isomorphism (he we need Brown's theorem) $f_*: \pi_1(M,y)\to \pi_1(int(N), x)\cong \pi_1(N, x)$, $x=f(y)$, we obtain a subgroup $G=f_*(H)\le \pi_1(N, x)$. Now, let $q: N'\to N$ be the covering determined by $G$. Clearly, $M'$ is homeomorphic to the interior of $N'$ (via a lift of $f$). Restricting to the case of finite coverings, $H$ is a finite index subgroup of $\pi_1(M,y)$, hence, $G$  is a finite index subgroup of $\pi_1(N,x)$, hence, $q: N'\to N$ is a finite covering, hence, $N'$ is a compact manifold with boundary (I trust you know how to prove this). Thus, $M'$ is tame. qed

Comment: Nice argument! I'm trying to understand it in detail. You write "Clearly, $M'$ is homeomorphic to the interior of $N'$ (via a lift of $f$)". Here, can you use the fact that $q^{-1}(\text{int}(N)) = \text{int}(N')$ is true and then use the lifting property of the covering $\text{int}(N') \to \text{int}(N)$ given by restriction of $q$? The pre-image equation above, if it is true, would ensure thiat this is in fact a covering and then lifts of homeomorphisms are homeomorphisms.

Comment: @abenthy: This follows from invariance of domain: Local homeomorphisms send boundary points to boundary points. This part you should do yourself: Any covering of a manifold with boundary is again a manifold with boundary so that the preimage of the boundary is the boundary of the covering space.